# How to make k-means algorithm functional

Tags: javascript, algorithm, functional-programming, k-means

I have a very basic implementation of k-means in javascript (I know but it needs to run in the browser). What I would like to understand is - how could one make this more functional?

It is currently full of loops, and extremely difficult to follow / reason about, code below:

```js
export default class KMeans {
  constructor(vectors, k) {
    this.vectors = vectors;
    this.numOfVectors = vectors.length;
    this.k = k || bestGuessK(this.numOfVectors);
    this.centroids = randomCentroids(this.vectors, this.k);
  }

  classify(vector, distance) {
    let min = Infinity;
    let index = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.centroids.length; i++) {
      const dist = distance(vector, this.centroids[i]);
      if (dist < min) {
        min = dist;
        index = i;
      }
    }

    return index;
  }

  cluster() {
    const assigment = new Array(this.numOfVectors);
    const clusters = new Array(this.k);

    let movement = true;

    while (movement) {
      // update vector to centroid assignments
      for (let i = 0; i < this.numOfVectors; i++) {
        assigment[i] = this.classify(this.vectors[i], euclidean);
      }

      // update location of each centroid
      movement = false;
      for (let j = 0; j < this.k; j++) {
        const assigned = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < assigment.length; i++) {
          if (assigment[i] === j) assigned.push(this.vectors[i]);
        }

        if (!assigned.length) continue;
        const centroid = this.centroids[j];
        const newCentroid = new Array(centroid.length);

        for (let g = 0; g < centroid.length; g++) {
          let sum = 0;
          for (let i = 0; i < assigned.length; i++) {
            sum += assigned[i][g];
          }
          newCentroid[g] = sum / assigned.length;

          if (newCentroid[g] !== centroid[g]) {
            movement = true;
          }
        }
        this.centroids[j] = newCentroid;
        clusters[j] = assigned;
      }
    }

    return clusters;
  }
}
```

Comment: what to you mean by more functional?

Comment: Written in a functional rather than imperative form.

Comment: we aren't a code writing service.

Comment: The code is written Daniel. It is more of a discussion topic.

Comment: we aren't a forum. we are a q&a answer site. if you have a specific question about a specific piece of code, then that works best for stackoverflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209171/discussion-between-dendog-and-daniel-a-white).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly can.

You could start with this:

```js
  classify(vector, distance) {
    let min = Infinity;
    let index = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.centroids.length; i++) {
      const dist = distance(vector, this.centroids[i]);
      if (dist < min) {
        min = dist;
        index = i;
      }
    }

    return index;
  }
```

Why is this a member function?  Wouldn't a pure function `const classify = (centroids, vector, distance) => {...}` be cleaner?

Then for an implementation, let's change the `distance` signature a bit.  If we curry it to `const distance = (vector) => (centroid) => {...}`, we can then write

```
const classify = (centroids, vector, distance) =>
  minIndex (centroids .map (distance (vector)))
```

And if that `distance` API is out of our control, it's not much harder:

```
const classify = (centroids, vector, distance) =>
  minIndex (centroids .map (centroid => distance (vector, centroid)))
```

Granted, we haven't written `minIndex` yet, but we've already broken the problem down to use a more meaningful abstraction.  And `minIndex` isn't hard to write.  You can do it imperatively as the original `classify` function did, or with something like this:

```js
const minIndex = (xs) => xs.indexOf (Math.min (...xs))
```

Note that `distance` is a slightly misleading name here.  I had to read it more carefully because I assumed a name like that would represent..., well a distance.  Instead it's a function used to calculate distance.  Perhaps the name `metric` or something like `distanceFunction`, `distanceFn`, or `distanceImpl` would be more obvious.

---

Now let's move on to this bit:

```
const newCentroid = new Array(centroid.length);

for (let g = 0; g < centroid.length; g++) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < assigned.length; i++) {
    sum += assigned[i][g];
  }
  newCentroid[g] = sum / assigned.length;

  if (newCentroid[g] !== centroid[g]) {
    movement = true;
  }
}
```

This code has two responsibilities: creating the `newCentroid` array, and updating the value of `movement` if any value has changed.

Let's separate those two.

First, creating the new centroid.  We can clean up that nested `for`-loop to something like this:

```js
const makeNewCentroid = (centroid, assigned) =>
  centroid .map ((c, g) => mean (assigned .map ((a) => a[g])))
```

This depends on a `mean` function, which we'll write along with its required `sum` function like this:

```js
const sum = (ns) =>  ns .reduce ((t, n) => t + n, 0)
const mean = xs => sum (xs) / xs.length
```

Then we need to update `movement`.  We can do that easily based on `centroids` and `newCentroids`:

```js
movement = centroids.some((c, i) => c !== newCentroids[i])
```

---

Obviously, you can continue in this manner.  Each `for` loop should have a fundamental purpose.  Find that purpose and see if one of the `Array.prototype` methods could better express it.  For the second section we worked with above, we found two purposes, and just split them into two separate blocks.

This should give you a good start on making this more functional.  There is no magic bullet.  But if you think in terms of pure functions on immutable data, and on strong separation of concerns, you can usually move in a functional direction.